# Convert GWT RPC to RestyGWT

Tags: gwt, resty-gwt

Our legacy application uses GWT RPC, we would like to use [RestyGWT](https://resty-gwt.github.io/), can someone provide me an example of converting GWT RPC to RestyGWT?

Answer (score 2):

Sencha's David Chandler gave a presentation on using RestyGWT at the [GWT.Create 2015 conference](http://gwtcreate.com/videos/index.html). Both the [recording](http://gwtcreate.com/videos/#rpc-jersey-resty-gwt) and the [slides](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByS1wxINeBWjaGRvMGtxR1ZPbDg&authuser=0) of that presentation are available. A working sample project was used during the presentation, [available on GitHub](https://github.com/turbomanage/listmaker).